# CREATE LOGIN - can't use @parameter as username

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, t-sql

I'm a developer and I suck at SQL:)  Please help me out here.

I'd like to create my own Stored Procedure that creates a Tenant in my SaaS database.  In order to do this I need to create a new SQL Login for the Tenant and then add it to a predefined SQL Role.

I'm already stumped just trying to create the Login.  Here is what I've tried...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MyScheme].[Tenants_InsertTenant]
    @username nvarchar(2048),
    @password nvarchar(2048)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE LOGIN @username WITH PASSWORD = @password
END
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Tenants_InsertTenant, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near '@username'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Tenants_InsertTenant, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I realize this should be straightforward but when your new to SQL and the SQL manager errors are as cryptic as they seem to be to me its better just to ask for help:)

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently CREATE LOGIN only accepts literals.
You could try wrapping it in an exec and building it as a string:

Add `quotename` for safety from sql injection attacks

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + quotename(@username) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + quotename(@password, '''');
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  That appears to work.  Is it better than using

EXEC sp_addlogin @username, @password

From what I've read sp_addlogin is deprecated.

Comment: I don't know if its better than sp_addlogin, but you're right that sp_addlogin is deprecated. From the conversation [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/ad63208a-48d1-4307-9275-5bf20a6386a5) it appears Exec() is the only official way until microsoft get round to parameterizing the CREATE LOGIN command.

Comment: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near 'quotename'.`

Comment: @Shannon Quotename() is only supported from Sql2008 upwards, that might be the problem you're having?

Comment: `quotename` has existed since at least SQL Server 2000, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/aa238369. The problem, and still true in SQL Server 2014, is you can't call a function inside an `EXEC(...)`. You can only concatenate string literals and string functions.

Answer (score 6):

Posible solution:

```
sp_addlogin @loginame = 'test', @passwd = 'test', @defdb = 'test'
```

Comment: `sp_addlogin` is deprecated in favor of `CREATE LOGIN`, alas (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173768.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @t nvarchar(4000)
set @t = N'CREATE LOGIN ''''' + @username + ''''' WITH PASSWORD = ''''' + @password
exec sys.sp_executesql @t
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answers from @codeulike and @Galkin I ended up doing this:

```sql
DECLARE @t nvarchar(4000)
SET @t = N'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@username) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@password, '''') + ', default_database = ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)
EXEC(@t)
```

I'm running SQL Server 2019 and combining EXEC(--> with QUOTENAME() inside <--) on the same line does not work.

If I understand the [microsoft sql injection documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15#wrapping-parameters-with-quotename-and-replace) using quotename to build a string then executing protects you from SQL injections.