# Create users dynamic names and assgin roles

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create user with dynamic names with a variable name

example :

**The following code gives a syntax error.**

```
Create Login @User_name WITH PASSWORD @password;
                USE database;
```

and i need to assign a role for created user ..

Comment: Described here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837358/sql-create-logon-cant-use-parameter-as-username

Comment: The link in comment above does not work  as is. Added an updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use variables for object names.  You can cheat

```
exec sp_addlogin @User_name, @password;
```

Either that or construct dynamic SQL, but make sure to use QUOTENAME to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: This Stored Proc has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005, you're better using dynamic SQL with CREATE LOGIN

Answer (score 9):

You can not use create login with variables. You have to create the statement dynamically or you can use sp_addlogin.
According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173768.aspx sp_addlogin is deprecated.

```
declare @UN sysname
declare @PW sysname
declare @S nvarchar(100)

set @UN = 'UserName'
set @PW = 'Password'

set @S = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + quotename(@UN) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + quotename(@PW, '''')

exec (@S)
```