# prevent SQL injection in CREATE LOGIN WITH PASSWORD

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

I have a scenario where I (unfortunately) have to call

```
CREATE LOGIN ["+username+"] WITH PASSWORD = '"+password+"', CHECK_POLICY ...
```

with username and password provided through user input.
In addition I need to do this without stored procedures.

I am asking about the best (correct?) way to sanitize these values.

I saw Microsoft article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-2017) which mentioned quite a few different methods and I am not sure which of them to use and how. In particular I am not sure which characters/strings to screen before, and how to use Type-Safe SQL Parameters without stored procedures.

I am Ideally looking for a complete/authorative solutions (link or code) as despite not finding anything I'm sure this was done before. Otherwise any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

(this is not the same as [Create users dynamic names and assgin roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991643/create-users-dynamic-names-and-assgin-roles) as I can't use stored procedures)

Comment: Can you just remove all punctuation from username and password.  What characters are allowed in usernames and passwords?

Comment: Any character that SQL server will accept for username/password

Comment: Please note that the accepted answer in the duplicate question is using a deprecated stored procedure. use Mikael Eriksson's answer instead.

Comment: Zohar see my question "In addition I need to do this without stored procedures."

Comment: How can it be part of your requirement that you can apparently run *arbitrary* SQL commands but you cannot invoke a stored procedure?

Comment: I can invoke it but I can't create it

Comment: @kofifus what is the *exact* scenario? How will you execute the script? If you use this command in a migration or deployment script you can use script variables. `CREATE LOGIN` is the same kind of command as `CREATE TABLE`. It creates a schema object, not a parameterized query.