# doesn't quotename work inside of exec?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837358/sql-create-logon-cant-use-parameter-as-username). The answer recommends using quotename inside of an exec.

Similar to this:

```
declare @var nvarchar(128)
set @var = 'hello world'
exec('print ''' + quotename(@var) + '''')
```

But this doesn't work (Incorrect syntax near 'quotename'). Is the answer wrong?

I know I can generate the string first, put it in a variable then use it with `exec sp_executeSql`, but I would rather do it the way in the question if it can work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best solution I could come up with for you is to pre-quote the value:

```
declare @var nvarchar(128);
set @var = 'hello world';
declare @quoted varchar(100);
select @quoted =  quotename(@var);
exec('print ''' + @quoted + '''');
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Transact-SQL Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx):

```
Execute a character string
{ EXEC | EXECUTE } 
    ( { @string_variable | [ N ]'tsql_string' } [ + ...n ] )
    [ AS { LOGIN | USER } ='name' ]
[;]
```

The syntax specification only allows string variables and string literals in this situation. Doesn't make sense, but calling functions returning strings is not allowed here.