# Create DB Name from SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create SQL Scripts to move old data to a seperate database.
The problem I have right now is that I want to name the Database from an SELECT statement.

```
use DBName;
declare @release varchar(max)
set @release = concat('Release_',(select MetaRevision from metarevision))
select @release

if db_id(@release) is null create database @release
```

Sadly this does not work. I get the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@release'
```

Is there a way to name a Database from an Select Statement?

Comment: `exec ('create database ' + quotename(@release))` or something like that.

Comment: To explain why: the parameter to `create database` is a *name*, not a *string/varchar*. In other words, **`create database XYZ`** is correct, while **`create database 'XYZ'`** isn't - and that is why also **`create database @release`** is not allowed.

Comment: as @ta.speot.is suggested you need Dynamic SQL for this

Comment: Is there a workaround? 'quotename' dose not work.

Comment: `declare @release nvarchar(10) = 'abc'; declare @sql nvarchar(100) = 'create database ' + quotename(@release); exec (@sql);` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I found a solution with the information of ta.speot.is and [p.campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029547/doesnt-quotename-work-inside-of-exec).

For the future, this is the solution:

```
use DBName;
declare @release varchar(14)
set @release = concat('Release_',(select MetaRevision from metarevision))

declare @quoted varchar(16);
set @quoted =  quotename(@release);

if db_id(@release) is null exec ('create database ' + @quoted)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it like this

```
declare @release varchar(max)
set @release = concat('Release_','TestOst') //Replace TestOst with your metadata
select @release

if db_id(@release) is null 

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

SET @SQL = 'create database '+quotename(@release)

exec(@SQL)
```