# Creating database logins and users from user input

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, user-input

I am using ASP.NET (VB.NET) with SQL Server and wish to allow a user to create server logins and database users from a web form.

I have gotten this working by executing commands that create the login and user:

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(
    "CREATE LOGIN [" & login & "] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = Db; " & _
    "CREATE USER " & username & " FOR LOGIN [" & login & "]; ",
    connection)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The `login` and `username` are user inputs that I am sanitizing (as best I can) and inserting directly in the `CommandText`. While this is working, I don't feel as if I should be doing it this way.

I'm hoping for something similar to parameterized queries, like so:

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(
    "CREATE LOGIN [@login] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = Db; " & _
    "CREATE USER @username FOR LOGIN [@login]; ",
    connection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

However, this does not work because `CREATE LOGIN` and `CREATE USER` do not seem to allow parameterized values, as mentioned by [podiluska](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638014/1405830):

> Incorrect syntax near '@username'.

Is there a better way of creating logins and users from user input?

Comment: @Jupaol: OP wants to create database [logins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx), not memberhip users.

Comment: what about stored procedures ?

Comment: @WaqarJanjua I hadn't considered it at first since `sp_addlogin` is deprecated and parameters didn't work for me. Thanks for the mentioning it though - your comment lead me to find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837358/sql-create-logon-cant-use-parameter-as-username).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option is to use a stored procedure, which I had previously avoided due to `sp_addlogin` and `sp_adduser` being [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173768.aspx) (as mentioned by [podiluska](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638014/1405830)).

However, it seems possible to use `CREATE LOGIN` and `CREATE USER` in a stored procedure by building them in a string with `EXEC`, which is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837358/sql-create-logon-cant-use-parameter-as-username). The parameterized query code snippet included in the question can then be adapted to use stored procedures with minor changes:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.CommandText = "sp_storedprocname"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't parameterise the `CREATE USER` and `CREATE LOGIN` commands.

You could create a stored procedure that uses parameters on the (deprecated) `sp_addlogin` and `sp_adduser`, but to create the user with a windows login, you need to use `CREATE LOGIN` and hence dynamic SQL.