# How to solve Sql Injection issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

When I try to create new login with `Login Name` as `'DROP TABLE Test --'` then it will drop's the `Test Table`.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID ('Test') IS NULL
       CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
                                [Id] [int] NOT NULL
                                ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @UserCode nvarchar(50)

    SELECT @UserCode = N'''DROP TABLE Test --';

    SET @SQL = N'CREATE LOGIN '+ QUOTENAME(@UserCode) +' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + UPPER(@UserCode)  + '''';
    EXECUTE(@SQL);
```

**Current Result :**
        Creates New Login as well as Drop's whole `Test Table`.

**Expected Result :**
        Only Create Login.

Can you please help me to solve this issue ?

**UPDATE :**

I have fixed this issue using `QUOTENAME(UPPER(@UserCode), '''')`...

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837358/sql-create-logon-cant-use-parameter-as-username) helped me to solve this issue.

Comment: What language are you using?  The answer will likely depend on that.  As you have demonstrated, if you put a raw login into your SQL, you run the risk of SQL-injection.

Comment: Why does anyone except DBA create new database users? Is this for some kind of admin panel? And even if so, wouldn't people just be destroying their own databases (which is not really an attack, even if they use injection to shoot themselves in the foot)?

Comment: Write simple Sql query... as shown in example...

Comment: One would think that QUOTENAME takes care of that. Strange.

Comment: @Thilo Issue is not inside `QUOTENAME(@UserCode)` rather it is in `UPPER(@UserCode)`...

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ gives you an introduction into the topic and how to deal with the problem in various languages.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which version/type of SQL, you could use tools such as [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), string sanitation, or [stored procedures](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/).

Comment: The question is so bland that this is really the best answer anyone could give at the moment.

Comment: Not really. You cannot use bind variables for schema object names (such as user names). And doesn't QUOTENAME already count as "string sanitation"?

Comment: Agreed. You have my +1

Comment: Can you please post some code ??? that will be very helpful to me.. I have gone through these links, already before posting this question...

Answer (score 1):

See this example...

```
 exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 varchar(22)',N'Select City, State from dbo.ZipCodes where zipcode = @P1','''; Drop Table Test; --'
```

Since it received the malicious code as a variable, the server would simply look for the value in the table and return a blank result sets. The malicious string is never executed, so the test table is never dropped.

Since I can't comment @ signs so I show it here.
See this link for details. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-injection-defense-in-depth/

I hope I helped a little.