# T-SQL: When string concatenation is the only option or how to correctly escape SQL strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, escaping

I'm well aware that the only reliable way to parameterize SQL statements is, well, with parameters, named or otherwise.

Unfortunately, it's not always possible to use those. For example,

```
create login [user] with password = 'p@$$w0rd'
```

will not accept parameters at all.

What will be the most reliable way, given the circumstances, to escape strings in T-SQL?

Comment: Does it allow expressions? Can you convert all characters to their codes and concatenate those? That might be "reliable" (but horrible to read).

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837378/163495) looks relevant, but if you're after a more generic solution then you could ask the database to quote it for you:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(@myvalue, '''')
```

This should return you a value that is safe to use in concatenated SQL.