# Trying to execute SQL Server command in pyodbc but getting error

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, t-sql, pyodbc

I have been trying to execute some SQL commands  thought python script using pyodbc but getting the following error.

Script code for Reference

```
conn_info = f"DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server2};DATABASE=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID={uname2};PWD={passwd2}"
        cnct_str = pyodbc.connect(conn_info, autocommit=True)
        query = """CREATE USER {%s} WITH PASSWORD = '{%s}';"""% ((user_create,user_pass))
        print("<-----random generated passowrd is----->")
        print(user_pass)
        cur = cnct_str.cursor().execute(query)
        cur.commit()
        while cur.nextset():
            pass
    def post_restore2():
        conn_info = f"DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server2};DATABASE=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID={uname2};PWD={passwd2}"
        cnct_str = pyodbc.connect(conn_info, autocommit=True)
        query2 = """USE [{%s}] 
        CREATE USER {%s} WITH PASSWORD = '{%s}';
        GO
        EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'{%s}'
        GO"""% ((dba_name,user_create,user_pass,user_create))
        cur = cnct_str.cursor().execute(query2)
        while cur.nextset():
            pass
```

error output:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\piyus\OneDrive\Desktop\sql_server_backup_restore_script.py", 
  line 129, in <module>
  post_restore1()
  File "C:\Users\piyus\OneDrive\Desktop\sql_server_backup_restore_script.py", 
  line 112, in post_restore1
  cur = cnct_str.cursor().execute(query)
   pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native 
  Client 11.0]Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error 
  (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Comment: Please don't use images for errors - post the relevant part as text so we can read it.

Comment: You have Trusted Connection = yes, but also UID and PWD ... how is it actually authenticating?  If it really is a trusted connection, then a) UID and PWD are obsolete and will be ignored, and b) the connection will be made in the context of the server / service. etc. that is running.  So, conversely, if you really do want to establish the connection with the user ID and password that are in your connection string, then you do not need Trusted Connection = yes

Comment: The code has a SQL injection bug, resulting in an invalid query. Imagine what would happen if someone typed `'; Drop Table Users;--` as the password. SQL Server doesn't use `UID` and `PWD` either, it uses `User ID` and `Password`. Those aren't needed though, since you use `Trusted_Connection`

Comment: If you use Windows Authentication you don't need passwords, you can create users based on their Windows logins directly with eg `CREATE USER [Contoso\Fritz]`. You can even add entire groups, eg `CREATE USER [Contoso\Sales]` which is more secure and easier to manage than adding users one by one - you only have to change the group to change who's allowed to connect. Finally, `CREATE LOGIN` doesn't allow parameters but you can use [QUOTENAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837358/sql-create-logon-cant-use-parameter-as-username) to pass the values as parameters and create a sanitized query

Comment: What's the **actual SQL** being executed? Take that SQL and run it directly on the target server.